# How do I make this program work correctly

Tags: java

In this program, I am supposed to check if each word in the file "Paper" is in the file "dictionary". If the word is not in the file `dictionary`, it `prints   out ("Line #" "the word")`. The problem in this code is the loop. I don't know to make the loop reset.
   EX: a dictionary file has two words **big** and **small**
       a paper file has a sentence *his foot is* small
       The program will print

> Line: 1: his
>   Line: 1: foot
>   Line: 1: is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
  public class SpellCheck{
  public static void main(String[] arg) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner readfile = new Scanner(new File("paper"));
    String word = "";
    int count = 0;
    while(readfile.hasNextLine()){ 
        String line = readfile.nextLine();
        Scanner linescan = new Scanner(line);
        String Scannedword = linescan.next();
        word = Scannedword;
        count++;
    }

        Scanner openDictionary = new Scanner(new File("Dictionary"));
        String wordInDictionary = openDictionary.next();
        if(word.equals(wordInDictionary)){

        }else{
        System.out.println("Line    " + count + ": " + word);
        openDictionary.close();  
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Please do not spam tags.

Comment: Sorry, new to this site

Comment: You're only reading **the first word** from the dictionary and testing it against a word from the Paper.  And this only **after** reading through the entire paper..  So if it does anything at all (I haven't tried running it), at best it can only tell you that the last word in the Paper is not the first word in the Dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how do I make so it can compare each word. New to java language

Comment: you need to implement a **nested loop**, in the outer loop read a single word from "file" , in the inner loop check if this word is in "dictionary' then back to outer loop until "file" ends, but **this is not the best way to do it, if the file is big this might take a very long time**, I am just commenting on your loop situation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, the file Dictionary is quite big actually. Is there a way for you to show me how? I don't really how to to implement loop good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather preprocess dictionary file.

```
while(readfile.hasNextLine()){ 
        String line = readfile.nextLine();
        Scanner linescan = new Scanner(line);
        String Scannedword = linescan.next();
        word = Scannedword;
        count++;
    }
```

Just like you have written here, make a hashset or whatever the container you'd like and copy over words in dictionary file. And, using another loop to do your task (check if the container contains the word you just read.) In this way, two loop are not nested so it will run O(n).